# Settings View and Material Design Navigation

Tags: android, material-design

I have a simple Android app with one main screen and a settings screen.
I would like to follow the Material Design so I try to understand what is the right navigation component to use:

On the one hand, I have only one view and settings view which means the bottom navigation is the right choice, [but in the docs it says](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage)

> User preferences or settings

Drawer is also not the right choice because the docs it for 5+ items.

So, which navigation component is right for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make setting part of the memu items in your app, something similar to this design https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/images/10_2_P_images/dg_main_settings_general_smartphone_composite.png